# htaccess redirect to url with query string?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I would like to redirect **domain.xyz/something** to **domain.xyz/abc/?querystring** via htacess.
(Most similar questions raised were intended the other way around.)
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

## Redirect Query String

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond (...)
```

<- a frequent answer but perhaps "the other way around" to what I'm looking for

Comment: What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have other requirements or directives in the `.htaccess` file then it's potentially just a straightforward redirect:

```
Redirect 302 /something /abc/?querystring
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. I don't know what I did wrong the last time as I tried exactly that (I think) with Redirect 301. Thank you!

Comment: @l-c-s If you had previously experimented with 301 (permanent) redirects then you may have been seeing an erroneously cached redirect. (301 redirects are cached persistently by the browser.) If this redirect is intended to be permanent, then this should also be a 301. (It is always preferable to test first with 302 (temporary) redirects in order to avoid potential caching issues.)